# Change layer style in database

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I stored the styles of my  layers in my pgsql database, and there is a need to change the style of a feature  if a certain field is updated.  I'm wondering if there's a possibility to set the attributes of the layer_styles table with an SQL query

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can update the attributes of an layer_styles entry. 
For example:

```
update layer_styles set styleqml = '<HERE SHOULD BE THE QML-STYLE CONTENT>' where f_table_name='TABLE_NAME' and f_table_schema='<SCHEMA_NAME>';
```

Comment: It wont work for me because I don' t want to change the style for the whole layer but just for the features which the status has been modified,  and I don't think that there's a way to do so even with pl/pgsql.

Comment: what about string replacement? I think you should add some data or an example...

Comment: I didn't get your answer

Comment: Add an example in order to clarify your problem. I guess you could do a replace the old value with the new value in the styleqml... but without data its hard to say...

Comment: Yes I did it and it worked but it changes the style  for the whole layer not only the feature which has been updated. As you know when you change the style of a layer, all the features are affected.

Comment: Then you have to change the style to a rule based or a categorized style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66650/discussion-between-aleho-and-zakaria-mouqcit).